# How to customize the authorization error produced by OpenIddict?

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I'm using OpenIddict for auth in a .NET Core 2 API. Client side I'm relying on any API errors to follow a custom scheme. However, when e.g. a refresh token has been outdated, I can't seem to find out how to customize the error sent back.

The */token* endpoint is never reached, so the error is not under "my control".

The result of the request is a status code 400, with the following JSON:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The specified refresh token is no longer valid."}
```

I've tried to use a custom middleware to catch all status codes (which it does), but the result is returned **before** the execution of my custom middleware has completed.

How can I properly customize the error or intercept to change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OpenIddict's event model to customize the token response payloads before they are written to the response stream. Here's an example:

#### MyApplyTokenResponseHandler.cs

```
public class MyApplyTokenResponseHandler : IOpenIddictServerEventHandler<ApplyTokenResponseContext>
{
    public ValueTask HandleAsync(ApplyTokenResponseContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        if (string.Equals(response.Error, OpenIddictConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant, StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ErrorDescription))
        {
            response.ErrorDescription = "Your customized error";
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        // ...
    })

    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        // ...
        options.AddEventHandler<ApplyTokenResponseContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSingletonHandler<MyApplyTokenResponseHandler>());
    })

    .AddValidation();
```

Comment: Great info, this allows me to customize the error description string. However, if I want to write my own raw json object to the response stream, how would I do that properly?

Comment: You can either simply add your JSON items to the `response` object (e.g `response["my_json_array"] = JArray.FromObject(new[] { 42 })`) or completely take control of the response rendering by writing yourself the response to the output stream (`notification.Context.HttpContext.Response.Body`) and calling `notification.Context.HandleResponse()` to inform OpenIddict you don't want it to apply its default logic.

Comment: WOW, a nice solution !

Answer (score 1):

> The /token endpoint is never reached, so the error is not under "my control".

In fact ,the `/token` is reached, and the parameter of `grant_type` equals `refresh_token`. **But the rejection logic when refresh token expired is not processed by us.** **It is some kind of "hardcoded" in source code** :

```
if (token == null)
{
    context.Reject(
        error: OpenIddictConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
        description: context.Request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType() ?
            "The specified authorization code is no longer valid." :
            "The specified refresh token is no longer valid.");

    return;
}

if (options.UseRollingTokens || context.Request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType())
{
    if (!await TryRedeemTokenAsync(token))
    {
        context.Reject(
            error: OpenIddictConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
            description: context.Request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType() ?
                "The specified authorization code is no longer valid." :
                "The specified refresh token is no longer valid.");

        return;
    }
}
```

The `context.Reject` here comes from the assembly `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server`.

For more details, see [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.Server/Internal/OpenIddictServerProvider.cs#L151-L177) .

> I've tried to use a custom middleware to catch all status codes (which it does), but the result is returned before the execution of my custom middleware has completed.

**I've tried and I'm pretty sure we can use a custom middleware to catch all status codes.** The key point is to detect the status code after the `next()` invocation:

```
app.Use(async(context , next )=>{

    // passby all other end points
    if(! context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/connect/token")){
        await next();
        return;
    }

    // since we might want to detect the Response.Body, I add some stream here .
    // if you only want to detect the status code , there's no need to use these streams
    Stream originalStream = context.Response.Body;
    var hijackedStream = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = hijackedStream;
    hijackedStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);

    await next();

    // if status code not 400 , pass by
    if(context.Response.StatusCode != 400){
        await CopyStreamToResponseBody(context,hijackedStream,originalStream);
        return;
    }

    // read and custom the stream 
    hijackedStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(hijackedStream))
    {
        var raw= sr.ReadToEnd();
        if(raw.Contains("The specified refresh token is no longer valid.")){
            // custom your own response
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            // ...
            //context.Response.Body = ... /
        }else{
            await CopyStreamToResponseBody(context,hijackedStream,originalStream);
        }
    }
});

// helper to make the copy easy
private async Task CopyStreamToResponseBody(HttpContext context,Stream newStream, Stream originalStream){

    newStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await newStream.CopyToAsync(originalStream);
    context.Response.ContentLength =originalStream.Length;
    context.Response.Body = originalStream;
}
```

Comment: The reason I consider the /token endpoint not reached is that the constructor of the controller which the token endpoint resides in never gets called. Same goes (naturally) for the actual implementation at the /token route in that controller. However, I'll be testing your custom middleware shortly to confirm that the workaround is working.